# "I love you." ... "As do I." Interpretation?

Tags: meaning

If someone says I love you and you reply “as do I “ it means I love you too right ? Or does it mean you love yourself ?

Comment: It depends on whether you're listening to the mouth or the heart. :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Which is the proper response to “I love you”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/170694/which-is-the-proper-response-to-i-love-you)

Answer (score 5):

Saying "as do I" is the same as saying "me too". When someone says "I love you" and you reply "me too", you usually mean you love them too. Same goes here...

Answer (score 3):

If interpreted literally, it would mean you loved yourself. Luckily, the meaning of sentences does not always depend on a literal interpretation of the words spoken.

This is called implicature in linguistics and refers to what is [*suggested* in an utterance, even though neither expressed nor *strictly implied* (that is, entailed) by the utterance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Implicature). This is part of the wider field of [pragmatics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pragmatics).

Answer (score 0):

"As do i" is more formal. It is correct but seemingly uncommon and the use of it should be done by not the locuter or our partner, e.g

A: i love you
B: as do i

While in monologue, the form of as will not be inverted, like:
A: she loves him, as i do

So, if you say "i love you" to your wife then your wife replies "as do i" or vice versa, it's actually ok as far as i'm concerned